# Why KMeansModel.predict error has started to appear since Spark 1.0.1.?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, predict

I work with `Scala` (2.10.4 version) and `Spark` - I have moved to `Spark` 1.0.1. version and noticed one of my scripts is not working correctly now. It uses k-means method from the `MLlib` library in the following manner.

Assume I have a `KMeansModel` object named `clusters`:

```
scala> clusters.toString
res8: String = org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel@689eab53
```

Here is my method in question and an error I receive while trying to compile it:

```
scala> def clustersSize(normData: RDD[Array[Double]]) = {
 |   normData.map(r => clusters.predict(r))
 | }

<console>:28: error: overloaded method value predict with alternatives:
  (points: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector])org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[Integer] <and>
  (points: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] <and>
  (point: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)Int
 cannot be applied to (Array[Double])
     normData.map(r => clusters.predict(r))
```

The [KMeansModel documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel) clearly says that the `predict` function needs an argument of `Array[Double]` type and I think I do put (don't I?) an argument of such type to it. Thank you in advance for any suggestions on what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Spark 1.0.1 but the documentation page you cite is for 0.9.0.  Check the [current documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel) and you'll see that the API has changed.  See [the migration guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html#from-09-to-10) for background.